# Why does TreeBagger in Matlab 2014a/b only use few workers from a parallel pool?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, random-forest

I'm using the `TreeBagger` class provided by Matlab (R2014a&b), in conjunction with the distributed computing toolbox. I have a `local` cluster running, with 30 workers, on a Windows 7 machine with 40 cores.

I call the `TreeBagger` constructor to generate a regression forest (an ensemble containing 32 trees), passing an `options` structure with `'UseParallel'` set to `'always'`.

However, `TreeBagger` seems to only make use of 8 or so workers, out of the 30 available (judging by CPU usage per process, observed using the Task Manager). When I try to test the pool with a simple `parfor` loop:

```
parfor i=1:30
    a = fft(rand(20000));
end
```

Then all 30 workers are engaged.

My question is:
(How) can I force `TreeBagger` to use all available resources?

Comment: Complete speculation however based on the documentation for the `UseParallel` option "if a parpool of the Parallel Computing Toolbox is open" it may be using less workers as its designed to work with the Parallel Computing Toolbox not the Distributed Computing Toolbox and as such may be limited to less (8 workers seemed familiar but I believe its 12 nowadays)

Comment: I think there was simply a rename between "parallel computing toolbox" and "distributed computing toolbox" at some point -- R2014a and b don't limit the number of workers to 12 anymore. As far as I can tell by stepping through the code, `TreeBagger` is simply calling `parfor`.

Comment: It seems in a little behind the times there... I agree totally having checked the source, `TreeBagger` calls both `smartForSliceout` for the main loop, which utilises `parfor`, and `getParallelPoolSize` (which is a basically a wrapper for `gcp`) to determine the pool size... So i cant see why all workers are not engaged... the information in the question indicates that 30 workers are active (unless some inherent parallelization in `fft` is hiding the fact the pool is smaller than 30 - this would be simple to check with `gcp`)

Comment: To clarify: When I ran my `parfor` test, I looked at the CPU usage for all of the 30 workers. All 30 workers were occupying 100% of their respective CPU.

Comment: just to confirm; in the PCT toolbox [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html#buaiofo-1) of R2014a. it says: `"Number of local workers no longer limited to 12. You can now run a local cluster of more than 12 workers on your client machine. Unless you adjust the cluster profile, the default maximum size for a local cluster is the same as the number of computational cores on the machine."`

Comment: @DylanRichardMuir: Can you confirm that: `p = gcp(); disp(p.NumWorkers)` gives the expected number of cores?

Comment: @Amro: yes, 32 workers are running on the pool.

Comment: Can you confirm that once you launch the tree bagger, the workload on the remaining 24 never pikes? I suspect there might be some queuing involved.

Comment: It appears as though at any time only few workers are engaged. However, most of the workers become active at some point during the execution go TreeBagger. It does appear as though some queueing is occurring somewhere.

Comment: I recommend to submit a support request to TMW. They might be interested in your feedback and should be able to point out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I have started a discussion with Mathworks. I will update this question if I have any more information.

Comment: Is this problem fixed in 2015a ? I have the same problem to, in training mode all workers are utilized but when in prediction mode, all workers are idle. Has disabling LocalUseMpiexec affect on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for the TreeBagger class it would appear that the operations required are quite memory intensive.  Without knowing more about the internal scheduling system used by Matlab it seems likely that distributing the workload across fewer workers with more memory for each worker is what the scheduler believes will be the most efficient way to solve the problem.

The number of workers used/available may also depend on the number of physical cores on the system(which is different from the number of hyper threaded cores), as well as the resources Matlab is allowed to consume.

Splitting memory intensive tasks across a less than maximum number of workers is a common technique in HPC for some types of problems.